# How to exclude the zeros from this mean function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am calculating the mean of a list and making it so that the function also excludes the zeros from the list (because division by zero is impossible).

I tried several things, here is my most successful but it calculates the sum instead.

I made a working function, but I have no idea how to exclude the zeros.

Here is what I tried:

```
list_value = [5, 3, 8, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 14, 10]

                  
'''
test code
'''
mean_out = mean(list_value) 
print (mean_out) #---> Prints 55.0
```

This is the function that works, but doesn't exclude the zeros from the list:

```
def mean(list_value):    
    sum = 0 
    mean_out = len(list_value)/sum
    return mean_out
```

The question is: How do I exclude the zeros from this mean function **without** using list comprehensions?

Comment: Why did you move the calculation of `mean_out = ...` and `return mean_out` inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

you're doing it right. you just need to comment out one line. -

```
list_value = [5, 3, 8, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 14, 10]


def mean(list_value): 
    sum = 0
    for i in list_value:
        if i != 0: 
            print(i)
            sum += 1 / i
        # list_value.append(i) 
    return len(list_value)/sum  
            

mean_out = mean(list_value) 
print (mean_out)
```

list_value.append(i)  -  Here you're appending the value back to the original list and that's why the loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
list_value_without_zero = [x for x in list_value if x != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the first one is that you're calculating sum of non-zero values but using length of all. Just calculate length of non-zero values using count and you'll be fine. So instead of "len(list_value)" use count and do count+=1 if i !=0

Answer (score 0):

Without list comprehension, to remove all the `0`'s from your list you can do:

```py
list_value_without_zero = list_value.copy()

while 0 in list_value_without_zero:
   list_value_without_zero.remove(0)
```